# jqPlot - How to catch double click event

Tags: jqplot

I'm using the latest version of jqPlot (v1.0.0b2_r1012) to plot my histograms.

To catch a single click event I'm using 'jqplotDataClick' as follows:

```
$('#myHistogram').bind('jqplotDataClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    // Do something
});
```

Is it possible to catch a double click event instead?

Unfortunately I've been unable to find such event in jqplot.barRenderer.js.

**Update:**

I've made the following two changes to my jqplot.barRenderer.js file:

**Register jqplotDblClick event**

```
$.jqplot.BarRenderer.prototype.init = function(options, plot) {
    ...
    ...
    plot.postInitHooks.addOnce(postInit);
    plot.postDrawHooks.addOnce(postPlotDraw);
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotMouseMove', handleMove);
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotMouseDown', handleMouseDown);
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotMouseUp', handleMouseUp);
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotClick', handleClick);
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotDblClick', handleDblClick);
    //$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotDblClick', handleDblClick]); I've also tried this but without any luck
    plot.eventListenerHooks.addOnce('jqplotRightClick', handleRightClick); 
};
```

**Implement handleDblClick function**

```
function handleDblClick(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    if (neighbor) {
        var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
        var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataDblClick');
        evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
        evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
        plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
    }
}
```

And then I bind jqplotDataDblClick in my JavaScript file as follows:

```
$('#myHistogram').bind('jqplotDataDblClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    alert("Ohayo!"); // Good morning in Japanese
});
```

However the double click event doensn't get fired when I double click on one of my vertical bar graphs.  I've tried binding "jqplotRightClick" but that doesn't work either.  **If I use "jqplotClick" then everything works as expected.**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

**Update 2:**

**RE: I've tried binding "jqplotRightClick" but that doesn't work either. (see above)**

I've just found out that in order to catch this event you have to set the following:

```
captureRightClick: true,
```

See: [How to capture right click event](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the "cursor" plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.cursor.js), they handle it like this:

```
if (c.dblClickReset) {
  $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotDblClick', handleDblClick]);
}
```

**EDITS**

I can capture the double click by just binding the 'jqplotDblClick'.  I did not have to push the event.  Sorry for the misdirection, my answer above meant to show that the event already existed.  See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/WAA28/).  The only additional thing I added was CSS rules to make the div un-selectable since a double-click will select it.

HTML:

```
<div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:300px; height:300px; -moz-user-select: -moz-none;-khtml-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
        var ticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

        plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {

            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                }
            }
        });

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDblClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                alert('hi');
            });
});
```

Comment: +1 Good one. BTW How would you serve this event only for one chart and not the other?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the pointer.  I've updated my initial post after doing some more investigation.  Would you be able to tell me why my double click event doesn't get fired?  I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.